# jQuery next() where to use it

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following function to load iFrames content when I click on the link.

I'm trying to implement the .next method to load one iFrame at time and not all together.

```
$('.toggle-next-div').click(function () {
var iframe = $(this).next('.myiFrame');
iframe.attr("src", iframe.data("src"));
});
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="toggle-next-div">Map</a>
<div class="slidingDiv">
    <div style="margin-top:0">
        <span style="float:left;font-weight:bold">title</span>
        <iframe class="myiFrame" data-src="www.yahoo.com" src="about:blank"></iframe>  
    </div>
</div>
<div class="slidingDiv">
    <div style="margin-top:0; margin-right:10px; margin-bottom:10px; text-align:right">
        <span style="float:left; font-weight:bold">title</span>
        <iframe class="myiFrame" data-src="www.yahoo.com" src="about:blank"></iframe>  
    </div>
</div>
//and so on...
```

The next() method doesn't work in my html  so I need an alternative solution for this html code

Comment: I think you are looking for `.siblings()`..

Comment: i have updated with .siblings() http://jsfiddle.net/bFhsS/13/ may u give a look? it seems it doesn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.next` selects the immediate next sibling of the selected element, i.e the `.slidingDiv` element(*if it matches with the specified selector*), you can use `.find()` and `.next()` methods:

```
var iframe = $(this).next('.slidingDiv').find('.myiFrame');
```

If you want to select all the `.myiFrame` descendant elements of all the next sibling `.slidingDiv` elements you can either use `.siblings()` or `.nextAll()` methods:

```
$(this).nextAll('.slidingDiv').find('.myiFrame').attr('src', function(){
   return $(this).data('src');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is what you were going for

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="toggle-next-div">Map</a>
<div class="slidingDiv">
    <div style="margin-top:0">
        <span style="float:left;font-weight:bold">title</span>
        <iframe class="myiFrame" data-src="http://www.yahoo.com" src="about:blank"></iframe>  
    </div>
</div>
<div class="slidingDiv">
    <div style="margin-top:0; margin-right:10px; margin-bottom:10px; text-align:right">
        <span style="float:left; font-weight:bold">title</span>
        <iframe class="myiFrame" data-src="http://www.yahoo.com" src="about:blank"></iframe>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript (jQuery):

```
var slidingDivs = $(".slidingDiv");
$('.toggle-next-div').click(function () {
    var iframe = slidingDivs.next().find('.myiFrame');
    iframe.attr("src", iframe.data("src"));
});
```

Comment: Note that your next shouldn't contain the selector, you should run a ".find" after to get down to the child element. Also - your yahoo url needed a protocol (it would be better to detect for non-cross-origin urls, but I assume you're not keeping yahoo, it has 'X-Frame-Options' set to 'SAMEORIGIN', disallowing your iframe to display it).